# How to gracefully restart django gunicorn?

Tags: django, gunicorn

I made a django application using docker.

Currently I send hup signal to gunicorn master process to restart.

If I simply send a hup signal, the workers are likely to restart without fully completing what they were doing.

Does gunicorn support graceful restart just by sending a hup signal to the master process?

If not, how can I gracefully restart the Gunicorn?

Comment: How are you sending the signal to the process? What command(s) do you run?

Comment: @Iain Shelvington
 just `docket exec <container name> sh -c "kill -hup $pid"  `

Comment: Add that into your question

Answer (score 0):

You can start gunicorn with the code:

```
gunicorn  --pid /var/run/gunicorn.pid --bind 0.0.0.0:80 --reload myproject.asgi.application
```

And graceful restart with the code:

```
cat /var/run/gunicorn.pid | xargs kill -HUP
```

If you use docker, you can use the code:

```
docker exec -it  my_container sh -c "cat /var/run/gunicorn.pid | xargs kill -HUP"
```